# Displaying Stores Between Two Times With Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to display stores that aren't closed. So between the starting and closing time.

I used Carbon, converting it to H:i:s (database is H:i:s), and used Eloquent to get all stores, where the current time is after the start_time and before the end_time.

```php
public function showAllRestaurants()
{
    $timestamp = Carbon::now()->toTimeString();

    $restaurants = Restaurant::where('start_time', '<=', $timestamp)
        ->where('close_time', '=>', $timestamp)
        ->get();

    return view('home', compact('restaurants', 'timestamp'));
}
```

Comment: What is the column type of start_time and close_time ? why not use whereBetween?

Comment: @Mike Both are "time" types. And I thought whereBetween was just for single rows. Someone just told me I shouldn't convert carbon to a string, so I took a note of that as well.

Comment: What's the issue exactly?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your condition is backward. It should be `start_time >= $timestamp` and `close_time <= $timestamp`.

Comment: I kept switch them around, they didn't work backwards too.